# Word for "to make profound"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means "to make profound"?

For example,

> This onion will [*infinitive*] the stock.
>
> These colors [*3rd person plural*] the painting.

*Deepen* doesn't quite cut it, and I can't use the imaginary words "profund-*ize*" or "profund-*iate*" in a formal setting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would a slightly different construction like "give gravity to" cut it?

Comment: What on earth is a *profound stock*, anyway?

Comment: @TimLymington: a stock that has a deep, rich taste, I would guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intensify. Enrich. Lend profundity to. Instill with profoundaliciousness

Comment: profoundaliciousness?

Comment: A word like "profoundaliciousness" makes it able to find [copies](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=profoundaliciousness&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either *deepen* or *enrich*. *Deepen* does carry a slight implication that whatever is being deepened is already a bit deep (e.g. a well or a pit); but you can *enrich* something which isn't already rich or deep.

Answer (score 0):

[**Enhance**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/enhance?q=enhance) *to improve the quality, amount, or strength of something* **Longman dictionary**: *to improve something* **Free Dictionary**: *to intensify or increase in quality, value, power, etc.; improve; augment*

- These onions will enhance (the flavour of) this stock soup.
- These colours enhance (the play of light and shadow in) the painting.

Answer (score 0):

[Invigorate](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/invigorate) seems to match what you are looking for.